# Windows 10 batch script to enable bluetooth and connect to specific bluetooth device

Tags: windows, batch-file, automation, bluetooth

I frequently switch between using my Galaxy Buds with my phone and computer. I've found the most trouble-free way to do this is to turn off bluetooth on one device and switch. What I would like to do it simply create a Windows 10 batch script that turns on bluetooth (if currently off), and connect to my buds. Is there any easy solution? It would save me like 4 clicks but I think I would appreciate the convenience.

Comment: $bt = Get-TroubleshootingPack -Path "C:\Windows\diagnostics\system\Bluetooth" 
 Invoke-TroubleshootingPack -Pack $bt -Result "C:\DiagResult" this is not exactly what you want, but it disables and then enables the driver

Comment: @AP What is in the `C:\DiagResult` ?

Comment: @not2qubit that's where the result will be - ie the logs/output

Comment: @AP
I was looking in the `C:\Windows\diagnostics\system\Bluetooth` and found all the PS scripts, so it should be possible to hack together one that only does the "reset" part.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pnputil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/pnputil) to disable or enable your Bluetooth driver using the pnputil driver servicing tool. As for specifically connecting to a bluetooth device through CMD, as far as I know, I don't believe that it is possible but I believe that you can in powershell.

(Looking at the Blutooth diagnostic files under `C:\Windows\diagnostics\system\Bluetooth`, they are all powershell and running it, may reset the driver, so it should be possible to use part of that code.)

```
# scan bluetooth devices
pnputil.exe /enum-devices /class bluetooth

# ... a long list of Bluetooth related items.
# Look for something like: 

Instance ID:                USB\VID_0CF3&PID_E500\5&2a9042b0&0&4
Device Description:         Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 Bluetooth
Class Name:                 Bluetooth
Class GUID:                 {e0cbf06c-cd8b-4647-bb8a-263b43f0f974}
Manufacturer Name:          Qualcomm Atheros Communications
Status:                     Started
Driver Name:                oem41.inf

# Disable this device:
$ pnputil.exe /disable-device "USB\VID_0CF3&PID_E500\5&2a9042b0&0&4"

Microsoft PnP Utility

Disabling device:          USB\VID_0CF3&PID_E500\5&2a9042b0&0&4
System reboot is needed to complete configuration operations!
```

Take note of Device ID!

To re-enable:

```
$ pnputil.exe /enable-device "BTH\MS_BTHBRB\6&6d7d961&0&1"

Microsoft PnP Utility

Failed to enable device:  BTH\MS_BTHBRB\6&6d7d961&0&1
Device is pending system reboot to complete a previous operation.
```

Don't listen, instead go into settings and toggle the Bluetooth flip a few times.

---

**`UPDATE: 2022-11-29`**

Strangely enough after having rebooted once, and now running the same *pnutils* commands in admin shell, I no longer get asked to reboot.

For completeness:

##### When Bluetooth USB device is disabled.

[image]

##### When Bluetooth USB device is enabled, but BT switched `OFF`.

[image]

##### When Bluetooth USB device is enabled, but BT switched `ON`.

[image]